# jquery trigger click not working

Tags: jquery, jsp, button, triggers, click

I am trying to trigger button click using a condition inside a JSP. Here is the code:

```
<%      if(condition){
%>
            <script>
            $('#filter').val(<dropdown value>);
            $('#inputText').val("<value>");
            $("#buttonId").trigger('click');            
            </script>       
        <%}%>
```

I can see the dropdown value and input, but the button click event is not getting triggered. I am using Ajax to populate a table inside this button click handler.

What could be wrong above...

Comment: What is it you are trying to do (after the button is clicked). You have not registered an event handler on your button.

Comment: I am concatenating html to build a dynamic dataTable (using dataTable plugin) upon the button click. If I use above code in document.ready(), I get a dataTable warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it in ready:

```
<script>

$(function(){
            $('#filter').val(<dropdown value>);
            $('#inputText').val("<value>");
            $("#buttonId").trigger('click');    
});        

</script>
```

Comment: I tried that and I get a DataTables warning message, I am concatenating html to create the dataTables inside the button click handler...

Comment: "DataTables warning (table id = 'custTable'): Cannot reinitialise DataTable.

To retrieve the DataTables object for this table, please pass either no arguments to the dataTable() function, or set bRetrieve to true. Alternatively, to destory the old table and create a new one, set bDestroy to true (note that a lot of changes to the configuration can be made through the API which is usually much faster)."   Seems like dataTable has duplicate first column.

Comment: @stackoverflowfan -- i see nowhere in your code where you are calling anything called 'dataTables'